# How to train an ALS model in Spark with a matrix instead of individual "purchases"?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe which is already a sparse matrix.  I would like to train an ALS model with that dataframe without creating a new user/item dataframe.  Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible. You would need to transform that matrix into a user/item/rating DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

As Eliasah has said, this is not possible at this time.  I did what he suggested, transformed the matrix into a user/item/rating dataframe.